# Iniate dataTable with paginate, but then disable it

Tags: javascript, dom, datatable, pagination

is there a way to iniate a table with dataTable paginating beaultiful as it always does,
and then after the dom is loaded, trigger an event (click for isntance) and remove the paginate? In other words, put all the records in the table again.

**UPDATED**

```
        $('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        });
```

i have this code above, with 120 rows coming from my php. Naturally the dataTable paginate it every 10 rows, so 12 pages. I want to iniate my DOM with dataTable paginating normally, but then, after i click in a button, it disable dataTable's paginate; in other words, show all my records in 'one page'. I am not sure i have described it well, anybody can understand me? hehe Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain me with some code ?

Comment: so, typically the Show [#] entries can have an "All" option, which will not remove the paginate, but show all records of the table...is there a particular reason you don't wish to use that and remove pagination via a button? if the other can work for you, i'll share code immediately

Comment: No particular reason, just thougt it would be easiar that way. if i can show all records by choosing this option 'All' you said before, it would work fine for me. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: sure can, answering below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two methods will help in showing all records in datatables:

iDisplayLength is the initial legth shown on the datatable

aLengthMenu is the choices that a user can have in the show [#] entries menu item

so for your code add these to have an initial display length of 15, with options of 15, 25, 50 or All entires

```
   $('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        },
       "iDisplayLength": 15,
       "aLengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, -1], [15, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
```

play with the numbers to your application needs to see what works best

aLengthMenu documentation http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html